# IsolatedStorageFile.DeleteFile doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I try to do something like that:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    if (store.FileExists(fileName))
                    {
                        store.DeleteFile(fileName);
                    }
                }
```

but have System.IO.IsolatedStorage.**IsolatedStorageException**: Unable to delete file.

What is wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that the file is opened by your app?

Comment: Are you always using `using (...)` when opening files? If so, they'll be closed at the end of the `using`, so you just need to check if the code for deleting is executed at the same time as the code that reads the files. Just put some breakpoints and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

So I resolve my problem by using `FileMode.Truncate` on opening file.

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        //Do stuff
                    }
                }
```